# Chromium quicklist not updating, any ideas?

Tags: launcher, quicklists, unity

I added this

```
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=User1;User2
[User1 Shortcut Group]
Name=Draconis
Exec=chromium-browser --enable-udd-profiles --user-data-dir="/home/xiaolin/.config/chromium/Default"
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[User2 Shortcut Group]
Name=Snoozie
Exec=chromium-browser --enable-udd-profiles --user-data-dir="/home/xiaolin/.config/chromium/Profile 1"
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

to:

`~/.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop`

then logged out and back in, even tried rebooting, also tried adding it with:

`gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop.`

Nothing seems to work, all I get is the default quicklist.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem could be that you have 2 fields named **"X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts"**
You can try the following:

- edit the .desktop file `gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop.`
- search for the field **"X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts"** below the label **"[Desktop Entry]"** and add the "User1 and User2", should look like this:

[image]

Finally add your code for the two shortcut at the end of the file. ***(without the X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=User1;User2)***

```
[User1 Shortcut Group]
Name=Draconis
Exec=Exec=chromium-browser --enable-udd-profiles --user-data-dir="/home/xiaolin/.config/chromium/Default"
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[User2 Shortcut Group]
Name=Snoozie
Exec=chromium-browser --enable-udd-profiles --user-data-dir="/home/xiaolin/.config/chromium/Profile 1"
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Hope it will be useful to you!

Regards.